# Flux/Alt setTimeout not updating store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toast, reactjs-flux

I'm trying to create a basic "Toast" like service in my React app using [Alt](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt).

I've got most of the logic working, I can add new items to the array which appear on my view when triggering the `add(options)` action, however I'm trying to also allow a timeout to be sent and remove a toast item after it's up:

```
onAdd(options) {
    this.toasts.push(options);

    const key = this.toasts.length - 1;

    if (options.timeout) {
        options.timeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
            this.toasts.splice(key, 1);
        }, options.timeout);
    }
}
```

On add, the toast appears on my page, and the timeout also gets triggered (say after a couple of seconds), however manipulating `this.toasts` inside of this `setTimeout` does not seem to have any effect.

Obviously this is missing the core functionality, but everything works apart from the setTimeout section.

Comment: Is onAdd(options) an event handler on Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the timeout is setting the state internally and is not broadcasting a change event. It might be as simple as calling forceUpdate(). But the pattern I use is to call setState() which is what I think you might want in this case.

Here is an example updating state and broadcasting the change event.

```js
import alt from '../alt'
import React from 'react/addons'
import ToastActions from '../actions/ToastActions'

class ToastStore {

 constructor() {
  this.toasts = [];
  this.bindAction(ToastActions.ADD, this.add);
  this.bindAction(ToastActions.REMOVE, this.remove);
 }

 add(options) {
  this.toasts.push(options);
  this.setState({toasts: this.toasts});
  if (options.timeout) {
   // queue the removal of this options
   ToastActions.remove.defer(options);
  }
 }

 remove(options) {
  const removeOptions = () => {
   const toasts = this.toasts.filter(t => t !== options);
   this.setState({toasts: toasts});
  };
  if (options.timeout) {
   setTimeout(removeOptions, options.timeout);
  } else {
   removeOptions();
  }
 }

}

module.exports = alt.createStore(ToastStore, 'ToastStore');
```

Comment: Yep that works, thanks! Didn't realise you can use setState like that inside of the store either.